# C++: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory CMake VSCode

Tags: c++, numpy, cmake

I want to include `Python.h` and `numpy/arrayobject.h` in my C++ script. But it cannot open these source files.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(myProj VERSION 0.1.0 DESCRIPTION "myProj")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)                                   <--- work
find_package(Python3 3.6 COMPONENTS Interpreter NumPy REQUIRED)     <--- not work
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(myProj main.cc)
target_link_libraries(myProj ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} Python3:NumPy)
```

**Error**

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
[cmake]   By not providing "FindPython3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
[cmake]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Python3", but
[cmake]   CMake did not find one.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Python3"
[cmake]   (requested version 3.6) with any of the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Python3Config.cmake
[cmake]     python3-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "Python3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "Python3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
[cmake]   "Python3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
[cmake]   been installed.
```

**Path of NumPy**

```
(venv) cyan@linux01:~/TEMP$ python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())"
/home/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include
```

**Question**

How can I revise my `CMakeLists.txt` so to include the header `numpy/arrayobject.h` in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing a lot of documentation for `FindPython3` or `FindPython` for CMake 3.0.0 so I'm not sure if that module included before CMake 3.12.0. Version 3.12 is the first occurence I could find in the cmake documentation.

The most likely thing is that you just need to change to using

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)
```

Updating your CMake version is probably the simplest solution but again you might have good reason to limit the version and just telling you to update isn't much of a solution.

Another hackier solution would be to use one of the paths from Python_INCLUDE_DIRS or Python_LIBRARIES do some relative pathing from there. Something like

```
set(numpy_INCLUDE_DIR "${Python_INCLUDE_DIR}/../site-packages/numpy
/core/include")
include_directories(${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${numpy_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

This however assumes that your python directories are setup as if they came from a python distribution and would in turn assume that everyone that uses this also has a distribution with the same file structure.

Comment: thx the problem has been solved by settnig a complete NUMPY_INCLUDE_PATH. Appreciate your answer!